# Branch cut of $e^{iz^{1/2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

Wolfram alpha tells me that 
$$ z \mapsto e^{iz^{1/2}}$$
does not have any branch cuts in the complex plane. However, I am skeptic. If this is true, can someone explain why?
[[Here is the wolfram result]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP5oG.jpg)

Comment: Branch cuts are arbitrary. What is more important are branch points. Your function clearly has a branch point at $z=0$ (because of $z^{1/2}$). There is a second branch point at $z=\infty$ and you should choose a branch cut connecting these two branch points in order to make the function single valued.

Comment: In general, if I'd be asked whether a function like this is analytic, is the answer yes, provided you identify the branch points, or are functions with non-isolated singularities like branch points not considered analytic?

Comment: By the way, wolfram does only tell you that $z^a$ has no branch cuts in the $a$ plane (which is equivalent to saying that $\exp(w)$ has no branch cuts in the $w$ plane). But this is not what you were asking.

Comment: The function is analytic, except for $z=0$ (where there is the branch point). In order that a function is analytic, you should check that the complex derivative exists. However, without choosing a branch cut (and the definition at a single point) the function is _not defined_. In general, you can understand the appearance of branch cuts the following way: you have defined the function on some small region and then you try to analytically continue it outside. The continuation depends on the path and sometimes, you will run into troubles (that is different paths give you different results).